# dynamically generate javascript expandable list

Tags: javascript, expandablelistview

I want to do something such as when I click a button on the webpage, it will show an expandable list, instead of showing the expandable list from the beginning. What I did is using the library mktree.js and mktree.css

```
<script src="mktree.js" language="javascript"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="mktree.css" />
```

then creating a static  tag and a button:

```
<ul class="mktree" id="tree"></ul>
<button type="button" onclick="showTree()">Show</button>
```

in the showTree() function, I built the inner content of the tree and write it to the innerHTML value of the  tag:

```
response = '\n<li class="liOpen"><span class="bullet">&nbsp;</span>Parent';
response += '\n<ul>';
response += '\n<li class="liBullet"><span class="bullet">&nbsp;</span>child 1</li>';
response += '\n<li class="liBullet"><span class="bullet">&nbsp;</span>child 2</li>';
response += '\n</ul>';
response += '\n</li>\n';
document.getElementById("tree").innerHTML = response;
```

but this didn't work. It showed a list, but not expandable/colapsable.

Do you know any way to work around this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/hhGdy/ Works for me, we need more info

Comment: you can see that it shows the list, but that list can't be collapsed or expanded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a function that does the hiding.

Every time you click the "Show" button, the #tree node's html will be replaced by the html in the showTree function.

The easiest way to do this would be to have the last action of the showTree function hide the "Show" button and unhide a "Hide" button.  When the user clicks on the Hide button, it would trigger hideTree or whatever you named your new function, and collapse/hide the list.

Comment: The expandable tree I mentioned is something looked like this: http://javascripttreemenu.com/jstree-java-example.html

Comment: So what I want to do is that when I click a button, this tree shows up on my page. I think you misunderstood that when I click on the button, the tree expands ..

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion.  You're using a pre-built library to do this tree.  Which library are you using? The link you posted above does not link to anything that looks like your code.  Please post more specific information about the problems you are having, or consult the library's documentation